# TSQL Getting the ident_current of a view this uses joins

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

Using the following queries, I am trying to understand why I am able to get the ident_current on one view, but not the other.

Here is some sample data:

```
create table temptable1 (id int identity(1,1), name varchar(100), [type] int)
insert into temptable1 values 
( 'apple', 1),
( 'banana', 1),
( 'cake', 3)

create table temptable2 (id int identity(1,1), name varchar(100))
insert into temptable2 values 
( 'fruit'),
( 'vegetable'),
( 'pastry')

exec ('
create view dbo.identcurrentworks
as
select 
t1.id as t1id
,t1.name as t1name
,t1.type as t1type
 from temptable1 t1
')
--drop view dbo.identcurrentworks
exec ('
create view dbo.identcurrentdoesnotwork
as
select 
t1.id as t1id,
t1.name as t1name,
t1.type,
t2.id as t2id,
t2.name as t2name
from temptable1 t1
join temptable2 t2 on t1.type=t2.id
')
--drop view dbo.identcurrentdoesnotwork

select * from dbo.identcurrentworks
select IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.temptable1')
select IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.identcurrentworks')
select * from dbo.identcurrentdoesnotwork
select IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.temptable2')
select IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.identcurrentdoesnotwork')
--drop table temptable1
--drop table temptable2
```

I am uncertain as to why I can get the ident_current on the view dbo.identcurrentworks but not on the other. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, how Is there a function or method of setting what the next ident_current should be in the case of dbo.identcurrentdoesnotwork

Comment: The most obvious issue is that the second view includes two identity columns, so which one should `IDENT_CURRENT` return the value for? But this may be a general limitation if the view has a join: if I modify `temptable2` to remove the identity column and just use a plain integer column, `IDENT_CURRENT` still returns NULL. And why do you create your views using `EXEC`, by the way?

Comment: Just curious, but most people avoid `IDENT_CURRENT()` and `@@IDENTITY`.  `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or an `OUTPUT` clause are the preferred means of obtaining newly assigned identity values.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pondlife is right - the view `identcurrentdoesnotwork` has no identity column defined because there are two identity columns in the select statement. You can verify this by running:

```
    sp_help identcurrentdoesnotwork
```

Note that as the others have pointed out, for most situations, one should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` instead of `IDENTITY_CURRENT`.

For more on `IDENT_CURRENT`, click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx), and for more on `@@IDENTITY` vs `IDENT_CURRENT` vs `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, click [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) .